# Update statement running for too long or not

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to working with this much data (20 million rows) and I don't know what I should expect as far as query duration:

```
update table set field = '1234'
```

No index on field.  This statement took 25 minutes.  The database is set to Simple Recovery.  Does 25 minutes seem too long?  Table has 9 columns with small data types <50 varchar.

Comment: What about server load?  Have you looked at Profiler to see if the box is taxed for CPU or memory?

Comment: You're updating 20 million rows?  Please tell me you have a where clause in your actual update statement.

Comment: @OMG Ponies:  We just installed Windows Server 2008 R2 and I looked at the sql server process, it is using all but 28 MB of RAM.

Comment: I don't remember windows XP allowing that much ram being eaten by SQL Server

Comment: @Beth: Nope.  Where clause is not needed nor wanted in this query.

Comment: @subt13 Are there other applications on the box or is it purely SQL Server?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

IF you updated 20M rows in one single transaction, then your time was entirely driven by your IO subsystem: what kind of drives you have, what disk files layout etc. If you have 40 spindles in raid 10 with 4 balanced files and a separate similar battery for the log then the result is worryingly slow. If you tested this with one single MDF that shares the spindle with the LDF on a single consumer quality 5000rpm HDD then your time is amazingly fast.

Comment: +1: Is IO always the issue for cases like these, or is there a vague tipping point?

Comment: For 20M rows in a single update statement is all going to be driven by how fast the log can flush, with some spikes when the DB checkpoints kick in due to buffer pool pressure for free pages.

Comment: The tell-tale sign is going to be the `Avg. Disk Queue Length` (>2 per spindle) and the `Avg. sec/transfer` (>10ms) performance counters. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175903.aspx

Comment: Good points.  This is a server OS running a server application using desktop hardware.  No RAID, single 250 GB 7200 drive.  That's what I needed to know.

Comment: @Remus regardless of the recovery mode setting (simple vs full/bulk)?

Comment: @subt13: Even in simple mode, the transaction has to log every row change so that it can do a rollback. 20M rows-> 20M change records in log + space reserved for 20M undo operations, it need log space and every bit has to be written to disk. The recovery model would play a role only if you had multiple transactions, but it would not make things faster no matter the recovery model. Only bulk *may* be faster for certain *insert* operations, never for updates.

Comment: Based on this feedback it seems like the 25 minutes is acceptable and if I want to speed it up, I'm going to have to upgrade the hardware.

Comment: You may give disk partition alignment a shot: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814%28SQL.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You are updating  20 Mio records in about 1500s averaging at somrthing of 7000 updates per second. Sounds about right.

Comment: because the order of magnitude is in the range I would expect, less than 1000 would be strange more than 40000 also.

Answer (score 1):

- Are there any indexed views referencing that field?
- Is that field published in a (transactional) replication scheme?
- Are other sessions accessing that table at the same time the update is running?
- Are the log and data files stored on separate disks (physical, not two different partitions of the same hardware)?
- Are there any check constraints referencing that field?
- Are there any triggers on that table?

All of these, and likely many other factors, will affect data modification performance.

Otherwise, try batching the update using `TOP` and a `WHERE` clause that finds only umodified rows.

Comment: I tried batching, but wasn't sure about the batch size.  I tried 10000 and it was taking even longer.