# SQL Server 2008 slow down after 30,000 user Insert from a busy Java web application

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008, tomcat

One of our system finally launch in production and during the peak hour (about 200 concurrent user at any one time), traffic can ramp up to 30,000 user transaction within an hour.

What we notice is a strange behavior that right after our SQL server restarted, the performance is very fast. Even with 200 concurrent user at the beginning, the transaction to SQL server 2008 R2 is less than 10ms. However, after about 15,000 transactions, we can see each transaction can take up 100ms to complete. When comes to about 30,000 transactions, each transaction may take up 300ms the worst case. If we dont restart the SQL server, even single thread, the transaction will still be around 300ms.

Each transaction will perform the following:

- 1 Select in Master table and and 2 select in account table, 1 insert or update into master table, 1 insert or update to account table, and 1 or 2 insert into history table
- account table (2 column as primary key, 4 column as index and another 6 column as data column)
- master table (3 column as primary key, 5 column as index and another 11 column as data column)
- history table (3 column as primary key, 4 column as index and another 15 column as data column)

Note: Some data column above is index above is because we used in the where clause.

Note: During Select, we does not join any table for performance purposes.

Note: DB Server and Web Server is actually the same server.

**System setup:**

- OS: Windows 2008 Enterprise
- Web Server: Tomcat Web Server
- Connection to DB: Spring Connection Pooling (Min 50, Max 350)
- Using the Latest SQL JDBC Driver
- DB Server: Sql Server 2008 R2 SP1

**Server Hardware:**

- CPU: 4 x Quad Core CPU (each core have 2 threads) that means total of 32 physical threads
- Memory: 16GB
- Harddisk: raid 1 on 4 x SAS 15K Harddisk. this means 2 harddisk visible for OS. Application data and OS use 1 harddisk while SQL DB use another harddisk.

Any idea where we can track and resolve the performance slow down after 10,000 transactions?

Comment: I'll see if I can find it, but Remus had an answer laying out that the issue is definitely I/O based - the drive/array setup needs to be faster at handling writes.  And striping is not something I'd trust production data to - RAID 10 if supported

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523831/update-statement-running-for-too-long-or-not/3523903#3523903

Comment: my own experience also showed that SQL Server sucks on high load. If it is consistently slower, that's all right; but the behavior is unpredictable and can suddenly crap out beyond reason. And internet can't help with these problems. Who's making the purchase decision and why? It has some fancy GUI frontend? Means shit if it can't handle the load.

Comment: The reason is $$$. Why SQL Server because our client have open license on SQL server and this reduces a lot of cost since nowadays, Database license count by the number of core you have in the server.

Comment: @irreputable, SQL Server is fine with high loads with properly designed datbases and correct hardware. I know people who work with terrabyte sized databases with a high load and they don't have these problems because they hired database experts with experience in high performance systems to do their design work. If you didn't then of course you have crappy performance under load, your designers didn't know what they were doing. But don't blame SQL Server for designer incompetence.

Comment: how can you blame user when question like this is asked? obviously it's SQL's bug that it gradually slows down to crawling. if you need high end hardware and expensive experts, why not just use Oracle?

Comment: First of all, thank you for the comments. I dont intend to blame anything or anyone here. All i hope is to check how to resolve this issue before the SQL server MVP can actually help us in 4 more days to come.

Comment: As for the link given by @OMG Ponies, i have probe the server at its slowest peak, and following is the results:
-PhysicalDisk: % Disk Time  (40% at its slowest)
-PhysicalDisk: Avg. Disk Queue Length (0.5)

However, even sometimes both the % Disk Time and Disk Queue Length is low, The amount of time just to select a table with (<15,000) records will still takes around 300ms. I am very confuse..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the harddisk Raid configuration is wrong. Nothing to do with choosing either SQL/Oracle here, main culprit was the "Raid 1" configuration .

We delay the actual launch date and re-test with two harddisk on Raid-0 and it seems the speed of SQL server is much much better (30% faster) and is more consistence. Also, we re-format the harddisk to 64k cluster size which is recommended by the SQL MVP.

We ended up with 6 harddisks configured to Raid 1-0 in the production box and it runs like a champ!

Problem solved!