# Changing a datatype in a table without reaching the transaction log limits

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, alter-table, select-into

I have a huge table with about 100 million rows in SQL Server and want to change the datatype from `varchar` to `nvarchar` like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table 
    ALTER COLUMN comment NVARCHAR(250);
```

**The problem is that my transaction log grows until the hard disk is full.**

I have thought about kind of a bulk transaction but this is basically only one statement.

Does a temp table work when the new tables are created using the new datatypes?

```
CREATE TABLE my_table_new (comment NVARCHAR(250);

INSERT INTO my_table_new 
    SELECT * 
    FROM my_table;

-- or

SELECT comment
INTO my_table_new
FROM my_table;

DROP TABLE my_table;
```

What is the best approach to do this?

**Any idea how I can avoid the extrem growth of the transaction log file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find it faster to create a new table, truncate the old, and then re-insert:

```
select t.*
into temp_my_table
from my_table t;

truncate table my_table;  -- back it up first!

alter table mytable alter column comment nvarchar(max);  -- no need to be cheap here

insert into mytable
    select t.*
    from t;
```

One caveat:  You may have to pay attention if you have insert triggers or identity columns.

Comment: Thanks! I have no insert triggers or identity columns, which is good. Of course my table has more columns which shouldn't be a problem, should it? Any hint for a script which does some of those conversions? Would you wrap each one (as described above) in its own transaction? Any other thoughts?

Comment: @Christian, you could convert as needed in the `SELECT...INTO` column list using `CAST` or `CONVERT` instead of afterward. That will allow you to convert multiple columns in one go. For NOT NULL columns, you many need to surround the conversion function with `ISNULL` to coerce a not null result column.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks a lot for the tipp for multiple columns. In general I think performance is not a problem, it's more related to the growing redo log in the database using the full recovery model, from what I have seen transactions might help me.

Comment: I think I have found some hints, at least for my single column case 
 here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419529/best-way-to-update-40-million-rows-in-batch and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10754665/change-column-types-in-a-huge-table but I am still unsure how I setup the batch in my case. Still unsure about the transaction log growth ...

Comment: @Christian, `SELECT INTO` is minimally logged in the `SIMPLE` and `BULK_LOGGED` recovery models. To avoid filling the log in the `FULL` model, you could load in batches with INSERT...SELECT like Gordan's answer both with a limiting `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

The following on the [Data Loading Performance Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd425070(v=sql.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) includes some discussion on the conditions for minimal logging.

If you can meet these (including setting the database to bulk-logged or simple for the duration, use of TABLOCK hint, etc) then you may be able to complete this without killing your transaction log.