# C# / SQL Server 2016 - Updating Approx. 100 million records with hash value

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, hash

I need to be able to read approx 100 million records from a SQL Server 2016 Database table, then generate hashes for one or more columns and write these records back to the table.

So far I have tried a couple solutions that are too slow for our needs. I am testing this on a Dell XPS 15 with i7-7700HQ processor and 32GB of RAM. First of all I tried using the T-SQL HASHBYTES() function with SHA1 hash but this was taking more than a couple of hours on a 100 million records test dataset.

Updating using a C# OleDbReader was even slower of course but the bottleneck seemed to be in writing the records. Now I am up to the point that I am using SqlBulkCopy to copy the altered records into a new temp table and this is much faster than updating an existing table. But is still takes me 40 minutes to generate all the hashses and writing the records back takes a multiple of this. Ideally we would want the entire operation to finish within the hour. Does anyone have an idea where I could optimize even further. Here is the code:

```
using (SqlConnection sourceConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
sourceConnection.Open();

SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *  FROM [ContosoRetailDW].[dbo].[FactInventory]", sourceConnection);

var dataTable = new System.Data.DataTable();

adapter.FillSchema(dataTable, System.Data.SchemaType.Source);              

dataTable.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(string);
dataTable.Columns[2].MaxLength = 20;

adapter.Fill(dataTable);

for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    byte[] toHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes((string)dataTable.Rows[i][2]);
    dataTable.Rows[i][2] = xxHash.CalculateHash(toHash).ToString("X");
}

using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    destinationConnection.Open();

    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection.ConnectionString))
    {
        bulkCopy.BatchSize = 100000;
        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "FactInventory_Hashed";
        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTable);
    }
}
```

I have already tried playing with the bulk copy batch size and I am using a very fast hashing algorithm.

Comment: See if creating a new table helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711217/fastest-way-to-update-120-million-records

Comment: batch all of this into bundles of n rows and run the operations in parallel?

Comment: Your current approach loads the entire source table to memory? How are you not getting out of memory?  You could try a streaming approach like and SSIS DataFlow with the hashing done in a ScriptTransform.  None of these will help you if the bottleneck is DB/IO.

Comment: Yes the idea was to load each table into memory, hash it and write it back. peak memory usage was about 9 GB to 12GB. This is because xxHash works at near RAM speeds so I thought having the table in RAM would utilize xxHash performance best. I will profile my I/O though to see if that is the bottleneck. On my small dataset with 8 million records the SqlBatchCopy is fast in just over a minute. So batching up the hashing as well and run this in seperate threads is something i will investigate as well. Otherwise i'll put in inside our SSIS data prep package.

Comment: You could implement your own DataReader to hash the values on the fly and use that as the source to stream data via SqlBulkCopy.

Comment: I usually deal with almost millions rows data. Seems you're needed to replace only Rows[i][2] with hashed value. I recommend to only SELECT required column because if it's millions, only reading might take long time but shorter with single required column.

Comment: the critical point in dealing with bulky data is you must avoid 'one by one' operation. We know bulkcopy is just a quick shot but inserting one by one with millions rows with for or foreach loop take long journey. This kind of SQL function does its best performance unlike one by one forced by you. http://mobile.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/getting-started-with-hashing-in-sql-server.html

Comment: I already tried the HASHBYTES function with computed columns but this was too slow. Also I don't need a cryptographic hash function so I am trying to speed up the process with xxHash which is lots faster than SHA-1. But if HASHBYTES already is very optimized I worry that I might not get very far with my own implementation instead. Although I will try reading only the neccesary column and I am trying the custom DataReader implementation as well.

Comment: furthermore, seems your speed limiting step is one by one for loop. just change it to foreach loop. foreach is the fastest one..

Comment: First, you would probably get a better response on http://DBA.stackexchange.com.  Secondly, how long does a null Update take to execute on this table (`UPDATE foo SET hashCol = 0`).  You aren't going to get any faster than that without changes on the DBMS side.

Comment: If on-server HASHBYTES was too slow, there is almost no chance that shipping the data to the client, munging it and then shipping it back to the server  will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old and nobody answered it. It might be helpful to review few things you are doing wrong in your code.

**1. Dot not extract all the columns from the table when you only need one or few of them.**

Instead of

```
SELECT *  FROM
```

do

```
SELECT <recordId>, <columnToHash> FROM YourTable
```

**2. Paginate.**

Instead of reading 100 million records in one shot, which really kills your sql server database. Try pagination:

```
SELECT recordId, yourColumn
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY recordId
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

To retrieve the next page, you can increment the OFFSET value by 100, like this:

```
SELECT recordId, yourColumn
FROM YourTable
ORDER BY recordId
OFFSET 100 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

**3. Extract the records in chunks (via pagination), hash the columns, update by recordId in batch and commit the transaction.**

It's very important to commit the transaction on every iteration. This will avoid causing sql server to keep the transaction open for too long, preventing other processes from reading and writing from that table.
You can create an SP for that. Something similar to this:

```
-- Create the User-Defined Table Type
CREATE TYPE MyHashedValueType AS TABLE
(
    RecordId INT,
    HashedValue NVARCHAR(20)
);

CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateRecords
(
    @RecordsToUpdate MyHashedValueType READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRY
        -- Start a transaction
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
        
        UPDATE yt
        SET yt.HashedValue = tt.HashedValue 
        FROM YourTable yt
        JOIN @RecordsToUpdate tt ON yt.RecordId = tt.RecordId;
       
        -- Commit the transaction if all updates were successful
        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- If an error occurs, rollback the transaction
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        -- Handle or log the error here
        -- Example
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorNumber INT;

    SET @ErrorMessage = 'An error occurred while updating records.';
    SET @ErrorNumber = 50001; -- You can choose an appropriate error number

    THROW @ErrorNumber, @ErrorMessage, 0;
    END CATCH;
END;
```

**4. Parallelise.**

Once you managed to implement the above algorithm you can parallelise by offsets and assign each task to a different thread.
This is sort of pseudo-code:

```
pageSize = 100;
offsets = Math.Ceiling ( (SELECT count(*) from YourTable) / pageSize );
```

iterate over your offsets in parallel and do something like:

```
ProcessOffset(offsets[i] * pageSize)
```

You can try this library:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-parallel-for-loop-with-thread-local-variables