# Merge CSV file values into existing Azure SQL Database using SSIS

Tags: sql, azure, csv, ssis

I am attempting to use SSIS (for the first time) to merge data from a CSV file and an existing table (People) in an Azure SQL Database to replace existing data in the table.

The CSV file contains an `Id` and a `CardId`. On the existing table in Azure there is a field for `CardId` which I want to be filled in from the CSV where the two Ids' match.

Here is the Data Flow I am using so far:

[image]

I feel that I am close with this solution. The only issue is that when arriving at the `People Destination` SSIS is trying to add new rows instead of updating existing rows, resulting in a primary key violation error.

I know that I could import the data into a temporary table and update from there. If that is the easiest way to achieve what I want then I will do that, however I feel that if I knew more about SSIS I could use the Data Flow to do this instead.

Comment: I think importing into a temp table then doing your logic there will be cleaner and easier to accomplish.  Additionally if your data sets you are trying to use get large, doing it like this could use a LOT of memory!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Brad, the way you are trying is importing data to the destination it will not do any update. You have to import the CSV content to a temp table, and  perform an update query with join to achieve your goal. But if the data is too BIG so it will take much time and consume a LOT of memory.

There are many suggestions for updating huge tables:

- [Fastest way to update 120 Million records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711217/fastest-way-to-update-120-million-records)
- [Updating rows in a large table in sql server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/168285/updating-rows-in-a-large-table-in-sql-server)